# Laravel routing - custom domain for same routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Say I have theese routes:

```
http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}
http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/page
http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/another/{custom_slug}
```

And I would like the same routes to be accessed from a custom domain, pointing to my laravel app's IP. Like this:

```
http://customdomain.com/
http://customdomain.com/page
http://customdomain.com/another/{custom_slug}
```

How is this achieved the best way?

**My current, ugly way**

I have made my own solution, which is rather ugly. It involves a lot of repeat-code, and a nasty controller. This is how I achieve it:

`routes.php`

```
/**
 * Serving from my app:
 */

    Route::get('/{slug}', ['uses' => 'MyController@show', 'as' => 'page']);
    Route::get('/{slug}/page', ['uses' => 'MyController@page', 'as' => 'page.page']);
    Route::get('/{slug}/another/{custom_slug}', ['uses' => 'MyController@another', 'as' => 'page.another']);

/**
 * Serving from custom domain
 */

    Route::group(['domain' => '{custom_domain}.{tld}'], function($domain) {
        Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'MyController@show', 'as' => 'page.customdomain']);
        Route::get('/page', ['uses' => 'MyController@page']);
        Route::get('/another/{custom_slug}', ['uses' => 'MyController@another']);
    });
```

`MyController.php`

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Find by slug or custom domain
     * 
     * @return [type]             [description]
     */
    public function findBySlugOrDomain($domain, $domain_tld, $slug) {
        if($domain && $domain_tld) {
            /**
             * Find by custom domain name
             */

                $page = $this->page->findByDomain($domain.'.'.$domain_tld)->firstOrFail();
        } else {
            /**
             * Find by slug (no custom domain)
             * @var [type]
             */

                $page = $this->page->findBySlugOrFail($slug);
        }

        return $page;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */

    public function show($domain = null, $domain_tld = null, $slug = null, $type = 'home', $custom_slug = null)
    {

        /**
         * Cases
         */

            if(str_contains(config('app.url'), $domain . '.' . $domain_tld)) {
                /**
                 * Incoming request to HOME (i.e. http://mylaravelapp.com/)
                 */

                    return app('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController')->index();
            } elseif($domain && !$domain_tld) {
                /**
                 * Request to page on http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/page
                 */

                    $slug = $domain;
                    $domain = null;
                    $domain_tld = null;
            } else if($domain && $domain_tld && !$slug) {
                /**
                 * Request to page with slug on http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/another/{custom_slug}
                 */

                    $slug = $domain;
                    $custom_slug = $domain_tld;

                    $domain = null;
                    $domain_tld = null;

            } else if($domain && $domain_tld && $slug) {
                /**
                 * Request to page on http://customdomain.com/
                 */


            } else if($domain && $domain_tld && $slug) {
                /**
                 * Request to page with slug on http://customdomain.com/another/{custom_slug}
                 */

                    $custom_slug = $slug;
            }

        $page = $this->findBySlugOrDomain($domain, $domain_tld, $slug);

        switch ($type) {
            case 'page':
                return view('page.page', compact('page'));
            break;

            case 'another':

                $anotherPage = $page->another()->whereSlug($custom_slug)->firstOrFail();

                return view('page.another', compact('page', 'anotherPage'));
            break;

        }

        return view('page.home', compact('page', 'js_variables'));
    }

    /**
     * Page: page
     * 
     * http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/page
     * 
     * http://customdomain.com/page
     */

        public function showPage($domain = null, $domain_tld = null, $slug = null) {
            return $this->show($domain, $domain_tld, $slug, 'gallery');
        } 

    /**
     * Page: another
     * 
     * http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/another/{custom_slug}
     * 
     * http://customdomain.com/another/{custom_slug}
     */

        public function showAnother($domain = null, $domain_tld = null, $slug = null, $custom_slug = null) {
            return $this->show($domain, $domain_tld, $slug, 'page', $custom_slug);
        }
}
```

Limitations of this way:

- A lot of repeat code
- Every time I add a new route, I need to update it twice
- Long and in-understandable Controller
- A lot of new complexity for the controller, in case we need, say two custom slugs in the URL (`http://mylaravelapp.com/{slug}/another/{custom_slug}/{third_slug}`)

Comment: just a silly question, have you looked at routing, why didn't you try to put the page route above the first {slug} route

Comment: Can you elaborate on that question?

Comment: sorry, forget my question. I was thinking you had problems with the placement (order)  of your routes.

Comment: why doesn't http://customdomain.com/page need the {slug} in the route?

Comment: Because on my domain, the {slug} references the specific page. When accessing the custom domain, there is no need to reference the {slug} as the "custom domain", references the specific page.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation, and I was wondering if this is what you stuck with, or went with a different solution.

Comment: do you achieve this sir @Mattias ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the app will be the same, you can use server virtual hosts.

In Ubuntu + Nginx, you can use [this recipe](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/26/creating-a-nginx-virtualhost) to guide you.

You can both make two virtual hosts or add, for example in Nginx, this kind of redirect:

```
server {
        #implemented by default, change if you need different ip or port
        #listen *:80 | *:8000;
        server_name customdomain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://mylaravelapp.com$request_uri;
}
```

Which will change:

```
http://customdomain.com/
http://customdomain.com/page
http://customdomain.com/another/{custom_slug}
```

To this, automatically:

```
http://mylaravelapp.com/
http://mylaravelapp.com/page
http://mylaravelapp.com/another/{custom_slug}
```

Another approach for [Apache](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost).